# PHP in_array() thinks that a random string and 0 are the same thing

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

Check this out:

```
print_r( (int) in_array('hello',array( 0 => 0)) );
```

It returns 1

Since you probably will have trouble believing it, here is a codepad: http://codepad.org/XlNKbrFk

Here is the official reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

> bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )

Yes, it seems that is_array thinks that a random string and 0 are the same thing.

So my question is, did I find a bug? Is this behavior justified? Is that drunken logic or what? Can anyone help me? I am struggling with that part.

Comment: Since you looked at the manual; the third parameter copes with that type juggling specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. From the [bug tracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=14343&edit=1)

> Not a bug... PHP indeed tries to convert 'foobar' to a number, and
>   because that is not really possible, it becomes 0. That's why there is
>   that third parameter too.

Comment: OK, so PHP converts "foobar" to 0? Because if the array contains 0=>1, it will return false.

Comment: It's not just `foobar`, it's any string value. It's typecasting it to an `(int)` from a string, which is why they made the quote above.